# Time cost of vector search vs. array search

Tags: c++

First, some background.
I'm creating a program that contains a **sorted** list of all lost-and-found items at a theme park, mainly just for schooling purposes. In theory, this program may eventually deal with thousands (or maybe even more) items.

I'm familiar with the clarity/ease-of-use reasons for using a `std::vector` rather than an array.

My question: When searching for a specific item in this sorted list, are there any significant performance reasons for why I should go the hard route with an array rather than choosing a std::vector?

NOTE: The vector would **not** need to be resized. It will be initialized at the start of the program (from a file) and never have items directly added to it.

Comment: Most vector implementations use a dynamically allocated array underneath, so you should get the exact same behavior.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel pretty sure that since C++11 it's not just "most", but all.

Comment: The search cost is applied to the geneirc algorithms not to the containers themselves.

Comment: @Raindrop7 yes, but there are differences between containers beyond big-oh notation. All else being equal, the same linear search is going to be slower on a deque than on a vector. So, the question is perfectly legit.

Comment: Side note:  for quick lookups, you might find the `std::set` or `std::map` containers to be more suitable than either arrays or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all a `std::vector` is (virtually) a *zero cost abstraction* of a dynamic array. Most of the vector's functions are trivial inline functions that get stripped away by the compiler. For that reason a lot of the generated code using a vector is identical to generated code using a dynamic array.

Second the *algorithms* portion of the Standard Library can't even tell the difference between an array and a vector because vector's iterators compile down to raw pointers, just like an array.

So, I would be very surprised if you could measure any difference given that there most likely won't be any. And if there is, you can always pass the vector's internal array which will, of course, be identical to using an array. Because it *is* an array!

Answer (score 0):

Go for vector, there are no real compromises in it.
Also, Scott Meyers writer of multiple of the most usefull c++ readings says:
`Item 13. Prefer vector and string to dynamically allocated arrays.`
Read the whole chapter, you will find lots of reasons why use vectors.

Comment: Im sorry you are totally right! was looking for an online preview and thats what i found

Answer (score 0):

There would be no significant difference between array and vector in terms of sorting speed, no. I'd go with vector as well.